# Ads not showing Android Studio

Tags: admob, ads, banner, interstitial

My app's ads are not showing. What's problem (Interstitial and banner)

```
Gradle Version 2.3.3 - Api 26 - tools version 26.0.2 (previously was working but not now)
Admob is added, added classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0' on build gradle, added gradle : compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.0.4'
```

```js
package com.elvearexample.myapplication;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.os.Handler;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdListener;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.InterstitialAd;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    
    private AdView mAdView;
    private InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;
    private Handler mHandler;       // Handler to display the ad on the UI thread
    private Runnable displayAd;     // Code to execute to perform this operation
    private MediaPlayer mp;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);

        MobileAds.initialize(this, "ca-app-pub-********1***1200~207****62*");
        mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(MainActivity.this);
        mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-**0***0999***44/103****7**");
        mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);
        mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
        mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            public void onAdLoaded() {
                displayInterstitial();
            }

        });

        }
}

        int Permission_All = 1;

        String[] Permissions = {Manifest.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE,Manifest.permission.INTERNET };
        if(!hasPermissions(this, Permissions)){
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, Permissions, Permission_All);
        }
    }

    {
    }

    public void displayInterstitial() {

        if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
            mInterstitialAd.show();
        }
    }

    public static boolean hasPermissions(Context context, String... permissions){

        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.M && context!=null && permissions!=null){
            for(String permission: permissions){
                if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, permission)!=PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){

                    return  false;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read about asking [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and edit your question to focus on the specific error. Are you getting issue, or are the ads just silently not showing up? Narrowing down on the issue and removing extraneous information helps us diagnose the problem.

Comment: the ads just silently not showing up